# Chirality in coordination octahedral compounds

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

[image]
Isn't this molecule achiral? I mean if I flip the mirror image on right by 180 degrees(like we do to determine chirality in tetrahedral carbons) it would be superimposeable? But apparently it is chiral. How am I flipping wrong?

---

**EDIT**
I finally got the hang of it (I think). Are the images below correct?
[image]

Comment: This is a $\pu {3D}$ structure. So use of model would be very helpful to see the difference.

Comment: http://www.chemtube3d.com/TM-Ru(en)3enantiomers.html it shows here but I still cannot understand :(

Comment: @yashasvigrover can't you attempt to rotate them in the link and see that they can't align.

Comment: Check edit please

Comment: I know it is optically inactive I just needed to know where I was wrong?Also it does not address the superimposeable mirror age aspect of the question which essentially the crux of the question? @mithoron

Comment: "I mean if I flip the mirror image on right by 180 degrees" when checking chirality, you don't flip the mirror image! You just check the superimposition of the mirror image and the original molecule. The mirror image was already obtained by flipping the original molecule, a second flip will always make it identical.

Comment: No it won't.You can rotate the mirror image as you want because if it is a separate molecule,it won't superimpose.Take your hand for example,it won't superimpose no matter what you do

Comment: This interactive image of $\ce{[Fe(en)3]^{3+}}$ might help you understand: https://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jmol.php?model=N1CCN[Fe3+]123(NCCN2)NCCN3

Answer (score 3):

See following image: [image]

Look at the purple loop (en) on upper left hand side structure. Now, if you rotate the whole molecule ${90^o}$ clockwise around an axis going through top $\ce {NH2}$- $\ce {Ni}$-bottom  $\ce {NH2}$, you will get that loop overlapping on similar loop on the mirror image. But, now look what happens to the other two loops? They are not overlapping on other two loops on mirror image. For example, the purple loop on bottom of left hand side structure will move to back side of the same side (it would be ${180^o}$ far from similar loop in the mirror image). Thus this molecule would not superimpose with its mirror image.

Comment: When you say 180° you mean 180°in perpendicular plane right?

Comment: See edit please